# unable to see specified fields in results when _source.enabled=false

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, mapping

I'm trying to create a mapping for Elasticsearch 6.7 but when I get a record I don't see any of the fields I've mapped unless I enable _source.

I have the following example:

```
PUT xyz
{
  "mappings":{
    "_doc":{
      "_source": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "properties":{
        "raw":{
          "type": "text",
          "store": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT xyz/_doc/123
{"raw":"hello"}

GET xyz/_doc/123
```

But the result from the `GET` is:

```
{
  "_index": "xyz",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "123",
  "_version": 1,
  "found": true
}
```

My expectation is that I'd get a result that includes the field I want stored, but obviously I'm missing something?:

```
{
  "_index": "xyz",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "123",
  "_version": 1,
  "found": true,
  "raw": "hello"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You still need to request the [stored fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-stored-fields.html) you want to see, like this:

```
GET xyz/_doc/123?stored_fields=raw
```

Then you'd see this:

```
{
  "_index" : "xyz",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "123",
  "_version" : 1,
  "_seq_no" : 0,
  "_primary_term" : 1,
  "found" : true,
  "fields" : {
    "raw" : [
      "hello"
    ]
  }
}
```